# 'If only youthness may come back a day so I may lament to it the grayness'

Tags: idiom-requests, poetry

Arabic poetry
يا ليت الشباب يعود يوما، لأخبره بما فعل المشيب

If only youthness may come back a day, so I may (complain/unbosom my feelings to it/tell it/lament to it/open my heart so it may sympathise with me/feel what I am feeling) what the grayness (signifies being old) has done.'

I just want to note that it's so eloquent in Arabic and so colourful because youthness is (Shabab meaning the youth) and grayness is (Masheeb). There's a similarity in the way it is pronounced and written. Gives it an extra spice. Maybe as english speakers, you can't see it but in Arabic it's extremely colourful.

Any idiom, proverb or piece of poetry suchlike?
It's said as a lamentation about what being old has done, limiting one's options & not being able to do and enjoy what one used to do in dint of ailment or inability. It may also be said as a yearning to something pleasurable that happened in the past & is now unreturnable.

Comment: Inclusive of pun, there's [**Nostalgia** ain't what it used to be](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NostalgiaAintLikeItUsedToBe)

Comment: It's a little more abstract, but there's "Ah, but I was so much older then / I'm younger than that now" from [Bob Dylan's "My Back Pages"](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/bobdylan/mybackpages.html).

Comment: There's also [this excerpt](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/7511-i-saw-my-life-branching-out-before-me-like-the) from Sylvia Plath's _The Bell Jar_. It's more of a lamentation about being paralyzed by choice in one's youth rather than regret for any particular choice.

Comment: Not to mention [Youth is wasted on the young](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/11108-youth-is-wasted-on-the-young).

Comment: From Louis Aragon: "One fine day, the future becomes the past. It's then we turn back and see our youth".

Answer (score 3):

> ***If youth knew, if age could***, Sigmund Freud

The phrase laments the inexperience and/or lack of wisdom of youth and the lack of energy of old age.

The phrase goes back much further; see *The Oxford Dictionary of Proverbs* [here](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780199539536.001.0001/acref-9780199539536-e-2529)

> Cf. H. Estienne Les Premices (1594) 173
>
> > O si la ievnesse scavoit, O si la vieillesse povvoit

translated as [here](http://thinkexist.com/quotation/if-when-you-re-young-you-only-knew-if-when-you-re/1206952.html)

> If when you’re young you only knew, if when you’re older you still
>   could.

Answer (score 0):

A certain song comes to my mind. 
May not be as descriptive a prose as you expected.

The lyrics to the song goes like this.

"God, tell us the reason, why youth is wasted on the young"

Clearly implies the young do not know the value of what they have until much later in life. And it causes them to yearn for the time which was wasted.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Alhamdulellah!
Every human must know which
In what way they spent their lives, their youth age.
It's necessary to use our eyes, hears, times, strength... in valuable things which is useful for ours in Akherat.
It's very very regrettable to tear our strengths without any consequences.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I do not see how this is answering the question ask. Could you please explain?

Answer (score -4):

Can this work with you? “Hoping to have the Youth returned instantaneously, just to tell it about how aging makes us live tenuously”
I've created it myself so, you can give me your feedback.

Comment: Please note Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum. If you have an answer, it must be your definitive answer to the question at the top of the page. The question asks for an idiom (via the *idiom-requests* tag) and your suggestion is hardly idiomatic, and indeed introduces "tenuously" which is not in the original at all.